# How to access executable in a separate partition?

Tags: bash, permissions, fstab, executable, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-partition)

I have just started using Ubuntu and I have my hard drive set up with an Ubuntu partition, a Windows 7 partition and a much larger Storage partition where I keep most of my files.

I have been doing some programming and have been putting `a.out` into a folder in the Storage partition.  When I try to launch it in Bash I got a permission denied error.  I then did a `sudo chmod +x a.out`, but this did not give any feedback so I tried to launch `a.out` again and got *permission denied*.  I tried using the GUI to change `a.out` to executable but when *I checked the box it unchecks right away*.

I did some googling and it seems that the partition itself needs to be given permission to execute.  So I did `sudo chmod +x Storage` and then I did `ls -l` and got:

```
drwx------ 1 jared jared 4096 2011-09-17 21:03 Storage
```

When I go back to change `a.out` it still won't change.

This is the line from `/proc/mounts` for the file system:

```
/dev/sda3 /media/Storage fuseblk   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

I'm sure there is something about permissions I am misunderstanding so if some one could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the line from `/proc/mounts` corresponding to the file system you're having trouble with?

Comment: Just did.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I had been wondering whether the file system had been mounted with the `noexec` flag, or whether you were using a file system that didn't support the needed permission bits.  I'm guessing that you're using NTFS here though, and I'm not sure how it handles the execute bit.

Answer (score 0):

Bash scripts don't have to be executable, you just have to specify what to run them with. For example:

```
bash ./script
```

Linux permissions (aka chmod/chown) only work on Linux file systems. They won't work on NTFS or FAT32.

Comment: Too bad he obviously wants to execute a binary file... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Windows file systems (notably fat32 and ntfs) and some others do not have a right management like their linux counterparts. But even it that weren't so, `sudo chmod +x Storge` would not do much as it is just a folder in the file system hierarchy and folders are already executable. You'd need the recurse option `chmod -R folder` to set the permissions for all files in that folder. But again that won't work here either because there are not permissions to be set.

However you can tell your system to mount the storage partition in a way that allows executing. For example my `/etc/fstab` entry for my windows partition looks like this:

```
# Excerpt from /etc/fstab
UUID=7258CB9858CB598D /media/win ntfs rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   2
```

Note in particular the `umask` and the `exec` option. `gid` and `uid` tell mount to which user the partition belongs to.

More information in these questions:

- [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions/46589#46589)
- [How do I give multiple users access to a Windows NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54321/how-do-i-give-multiple-users-access-to-a-windows-ntfs-partition/54324#54324)