# Is it possible to allow the User Account to access the 'Volumes' without asking the Administrator's password?

Tags: 14.04, users

Am the administrator of my Ubuntu system. Recently I added a new user account. But when ever the user tries to access or open the 'Volumes'(Drives where movies, songs and other files are stored) it asks for the Administrator's password. I created the user account to my other family members and I don't want to tell them my password.

So is it possible to allow them to access the Volumes without asking Administrator's password ?

---

UPDATE 1:

Ubuntu was installed alongside Windows in my system. I will provide a screenshot of the Volume details -

[image]

UPDATE 2:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried un-mounting the device from your admin account, then re-mounting it under their account?

Comment: @Jonah What you mean by that ?

Comment: It is an NTFS Volume or an ext2/3/4? Can you post the output from `sudo fdisk -l` please and [add it to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/474014/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`

Than open the account manager:

[image]

Click on "Manage Groups" then create a new group and add your two users:

[image]

(if you don't want to install a GUI for groups you can create a new group from command line)

Now we have to change the `/etc/fstab` run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

and add for the first Volume (at the end of the file):

```
/dev/sda5 /media/Volume1 ntfs rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137,gid=1002,uid=1000 0 2
```

"gid" must be the group id from your new group.

"dmask" are the permissions for the directories:

- 0 at the beginning is for the owner (in this case the user with the
  id 1000 should be your admin user) he has all permissions ( 0 ->
  read, write and execute)
- 2 as the second digit is for all users in the group 1002 ( 2 -> read
  and execute)
- 7 at the end is for others ( 7 -> no permissions )

"fmask" are the permissions for the files: 1 -> read and write 3 -> read only  7 -> no permissions

For more info look also at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/54324/265974

---

**Edit:**

Mountpoints for the other partitions:

```
/dev/sda6 /media/Volume2 ntfs rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137,gid=1002,uid=1000 0 2
/dev/sda7 /media/Volume3 ntfs rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137,gid=1002,uid=1000 0 2
```

Comment: Will the user be able to delete or add files, if I did like you said ?

Comment: @Tom Ok i changed it now the user in the group can only read files.

Comment: What you mean by this - "Click on "Manage Groups" then create a new group and add your two users:" ? Who are the 2 users ? Is it the administrator and the user ?

Comment: You can add your admin but it is not necessary because if he has the uid 1000 he as full access to the partition.

Comment: I said as you did. But now the user is not able to access 2 partitons - sda5 and sda6. Why did this happened ?

Comment: When the user clicks on the other 2 partitions, then password is asked.

Comment: Ok seems to be right but i gave you only an example for 1 partition, you have to add the others same way, i will edit my answer.