# New 1TB disk works with 18.04 but not 22.04

Tags: hard-drive, 22.04, read-only

Just bought a 1TB Element USB disk. I have several before and have had no problems.
I have no problem using the new disk when connected to my laptop running ubuntu 18.04.

Here is the partition table (GPT)

```
(parted) print
Model: WD Elements 2621 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name      Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ntfs         Elements  msftdata
```

However, when I connect it to a desktop running a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04, the disk does not automount. As you can see below, I can mount it but no more:
I get the information that the filesystem is read only and that I have no permissions for anything, like this:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/bjorn
$ ls /media/bjorn
ls: cannot open directory '/media/bjorn': Permission denied
$ sudo ls -al /media/bjorn
total 208
dr-x------ 1 root root   4096 jul  2 17:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 jul  1 20:44 ..
-r-------- 1 root root 202463 jul  2 17:32 TM-taket.jpg
$ sudo chmod 1755 /media/bjorn
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/bjorn': Read-only file system
$ sudo su
# chmod +r /media/bjorn
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/bjorn': Read-only file system
# sudo chmod +r /media/bjorn
# chown bjorn.bjorn /media/bjorn
chown: changing ownership of '/media/bjorn': Read-only file system
root@garage:/home/bjorn#
```

What can I do? Make a new label and reformat?

Comment: Can you try to do a `chkdsk` on this disk on a Windows machine? If you do not have a Windows machine, you can try the `ntfsfix` command on Ubuntu; however it has very limited functionality.

Answer (score 14):

- it is an NTFS filesystem and that is Windows.
- chmod is a Linux command so useless on Windows.
- The mount command is not correct so that is more likely the problem ...
- ... but if the NTFS filesystem is damaged (ie. dirty) Linux will never mount it writable to prevent data-loss. It is considered dirty if you can boot from a partition and let Windows hibernate it. Unlikely for an external USB but it can also happen with normal useage. Use Windows `chkdsk` to fix it. If it is due to hibernation you will need to disable it (from within Windows).

> What can I do? Make a new label and reformat?

Options:

- If the disk is not damaged and you want to stick with NTFS: You need to mount the partition to have write permissions. The command would be something like:

  ```
  sudo mount -o rw -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/bjorn
  ```

  - rw meaning read write.
  - ntfs as a filesystem
  - it is possible to add a user and group. Add `-o umask=000,allow_other` to fully open the partition to read/write/execute by all users. The 000 are reversed chmod permissions so adjust accordingly.
  - See also [How do I give multiple users access to a Windows NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54321/how-do-i-give-multiple-users-access-to-a-windows-ntfs-partition)
  - See [How to mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab) on how to add NTFS to `/etc/fstab` for a permanent mount
- If you do not have Windows or do not care for NTFS you can format the disk (use `gparted` for it; It will remove all contents of the disk) and make it `ext4`. If you do that you can do

  ```
  sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/bjorn
  ```

  and your current user will own the partition. If you have 2 or more users that need to use it put them in a group and change the second $USER to that group.

Comment: On the spot. I went for the second option, did exacly as suggested and have nor more problems.

Comment: @sa0bxi:  `ext4` isn't the only good option.  For a single disk, `btrfs` is quite good, and has the reliability advantage of storing checksums for data and metadata.  I'd definitely recommend reading up on the available filesystems and considering ones other than EXT4.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04: Why not use `ntfs3`?

Comment: @PeterCordes ext4 is still the default filesystem for new installs. Which, if nothing else, means that if there are problems, there's more information out there on solving them.

Comment: @iBug: One reason to be cautious of recommending the in-kernel `ntfs3` is that there's no active maintainer, mere months after getting it merged into mainline Linux :(.  https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NTFS3-Linux-Driver-2022-Sad Or at least there was, apparently the one guy that works on it is back now: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.19-NTFS3-Fixes .  But anyway, clearly in a substantially less robust maintainership situation than BTRFS or EXT4.  Of course if you *do* want to leave it formatted as NTFS, the in-kernel driver is probably good.

Comment: @PeterCordes The situation was more stupid than you'd think. It's simply because [Paragon's new maintainers weren't prepared](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/0f48e2eb2b0740b1b85e3b8d910c4bd8@paragon-software.com/) to submit patches "the Linux way" than adding pull requests on GitHub.

Comment: @PeterCordes Stories aside, the NTFS3 driver is substantially better than the decades-old NTFS-3G project, which had more compatibility and stability issues, as well as sufferings from being a FUSE implementation.

Comment: @iBug: Thanks for the clarification.  Anyway, I use BTRFS on my external drives where I don't care about compat with other OSes, and I'd recommend it to others.  It's probably even more stable than NTFS3, and more importantly it's a better filesystem than NTFS for many purposes.  It can detect bit-rot via software checksum, which for me is the main selling point.  It can be a bit slow on SMR magnetic drives due to the amount of writes metadata operations generate (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08514.pdf), but I've found it generally fine.  Some distros are switching to BTRFS as the default.

Comment: @iBug: BTRFS transparent compression can use zstd, which is very fast compared to NTFS's older compression algorithms.