# Mount and share USB disk on Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: server, mount, samba, drive, usb-drive

I've just installed and configured a house server with Ubuntu 10.04 (LTS). Everything works fine, but I have a problem:

I want to connect and share with Samba a USB Disk formatted in ext4. I tried to mount the unit but I couldn't do it. I want to have mount this unit all the time, so if I reboot the server I can still access to the unit.

I have Samba installed and Working

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate in detail.how usb disk be in ext54 format it always in fat32

Comment: How exactly did you try to mount it and what is was the error message? You might want to have a look at these answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions/46589#46589 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/50357/how-to-run-a-shell-script-when-a-new-usb-storage-device-is-detected/50388#50388 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/54321/how-do-i-give-multiple-users-access-to-a-windows-ntfs-partition/54324#54324

Comment: Can you clarify.  Are you talking about an external hard drive, over USB?  (If so, what capacity?)  What OS was used to format the drive?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post the output of:

```
mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Where sdXY is the device you are trying to mount.

If you dont know what is the device you want to mount, connect it to the USB port, wait 5 seconds e type the command

```
dmesg
```

You will see the new attached USB device (Example: **sdb1**)

Regards,