# How to auto-scan any plugged in usb storage device with clamav?

Tags: clamav

I'd like to do an automatic virus scan on any plugged in usb device using ClamAV. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

The closest thing I found was:

- [Run clamav on mount of flashdrive](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/run-clamav-on-mount-of-flashdrive-797286/)
- [How to run a shell script when a new USB storage device is detected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50357/how-to-run-a-shell-script-when-a-new-usb-storage-device-is-detected)

The first one is not working for me and the second one seems to target a known device.

Is there a tutorial around I've missed? Or can I get some help with `udev` rules that apply to any usb storage device added? Currently nothing seems to do anything.

Comment: You can write an udev rule for this.

Comment: Check out this one: superuser.com/questions/305723/… where RUN+= (location of file) is how it is read I believe.

Answer (score 5):

This is an automated script. Just run it as root. You can change the command executed by editing `/usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#doOnUSBinsert_0.2.sh
#Author : Totti
# Make it executable by running 'sudo chmod  x doOnUSBinsert_0.2.sh'


if ! [ -f /etc/udev/rules.d/80-doOnUSBinsert.rules ]
then        # rule not added
   cp "$0" /usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert
   chmod u x /usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert

#   echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN ="/path/to/script.sh"' | sudo tee     /etc/udev/rules.d/80-clamscan.rules
   echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN ="/usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert & "' | tee     /etc/udev/rules.d/80-doOnUSBinsert.rules
   if  [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
     echo 'Rule Successfully added. See file "/usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert" if you wish to edit the command'
     exit 0
    else
     echo 'ERROR while adding rule'
     exit 1
   fi
fi



lfile="/tmp/doOnUSBinsert.log"     # udev
lfile2="/tmp/clamscanFromUdev.log"   # clamscan
lfile3="/tmp/doOnUSBinsert_mount.log"   # mount


main ()
{
sleep 12  # let the partitions to mount

   #cat /proc/$$/environ | tr '�' 'n' >> /tmp/udevEnvirn.txt
echo "found $ID_SERIAL"   >> "$lfile"
  cat /etc/mtab | grep "^$part_c"   >> "$lfile.3"

if [ "$ID_SERIAL"x = 'x' ]
then
 echo "Exiting on empty ID_SERIAL"   >> "$lfile"
 exit 1
fi

#Eg: ID_SERIAL --> /dev/disk/by-id/usb-sandisk....42343254343543
#i=0
echo 'searching partitions'   >> "$lfile"

for partitionPath in  $( find /dev/disk/by-id/ -name "*$ID_SERIAL*part*" )
do
  echo "current partition = $partitionPath"   >> "$lfile"
 # part[i  ]="$( readlink -f "$partition" )"        # Eg Output: /dev/sdb1     , /dev/sdb2
  part_c="$( readlink -f $partitionPath )"   
  mpoint="$( cat /etc/mtab | grep "^$part_c"  | awk '{print $2}' )"

  echo "partitionPath= $partitionPath, part = $part_c, mountpoint=  $mpoint"  >>     "$lfile"

  echo "Scaning -->  $mpoint"  >> "$lfile.2"
  ############################################
  clamscan -r --bell "$mpoint"/*  >> "$lfile.2"
  #############################################
done
}


main &
echo ______________________________________  >> "$lfile"
exit 0
```

Comment: why are you repeating your answer and why are you asking for someone to edit the post?

Comment: @Fischer How does it work?

Comment: well I ran it and it gives `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert & "
Rule Successfully added. See file "/usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert" to edit     command` so  it works but I can't find the log file in /tmp

Comment: Code Updated . /tmp/doOnUSBinsert.log for udev.
/tmp/clamscanFromUdev.log for clamscan.  Run `rm /etc/udev/rules.d/80-doOnUSBinsert.rules` before running the updated script.

Answer (score 1):

In `System` > `Preferences` > `Removable Drives and Media` there is a section to run automatically a program when USB is plugged.

Here add the following command:

```
clamscan -r -z /media
```

Comment: `clamscan -r -z /media` doesn't scan automatically, I have to plug the usb and run it from terminal... about system, what system? there's no section called `system` on my xubuntu

Comment: In the dash, type `ibus`. Or in terminal type `alacarte`. Or it is under the shutdown button.

Comment: i'm on xubuntu, no unity no dash. Xfce desktop

Comment: No such option exists in Ubuntu 15.04.